# Python PIL - open image from file object: File not open for reading

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
imgfile = open('myimage.png', 'wb')
imgfile.write(decodestring(base64_image))

f = Image.open(imgfile)

imgfile.close()
```

i am being able to `write()` base64 string as image into `imgfile`. but when I try to open this file with PIL, i am getting

```
File not open for reading
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, itwas typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the file for writing, not reading. You'd have to use a dual mode, and first rewind the file pointer:

```
with open('myimage.png', 'w+b') as imgfile:
    imgfile.write(decodestring(base64_image))
    imgfile.seek(0)
    f = Image.open(imgfile)
```

Here `w+` means writing and reading, see the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> `'+'`
>   open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)
>
> For binary read-write access, the mode `'w+b'` opens and truncates the file to 0 bytes. `'r+b'` opens the file without truncation.

However, there isn't really any need to use a file on disk here; use an in-memory file instead:

```
from io import BytesIO

imgfile = BytesIO(decodestring(base64_image))
f = Image.open(imgfile)
```

Comment: fantastic! thank you.  i am jealous for the hats btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are opening the file for *writing* with `wb`, use `w+b` to open for reading as well.

Detailed explanation [in the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).